# Visual Studio Code, expand folder by double click

Tags: visual-studio-code

My expectation is, when I click the folder like `examples` is to "select" it, so I can perform rename or something else. But actually, when I click it, it will expand then I can perform some actions, I don't want it to expand most of cases though.
[image]

I can hold Ctrl and click, this can be my expected effect, but is there any way more convenient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to settings `File->Preferences->Settings` or by pressing `CTRL + ,` and search for `tree.expandMode` and there you can set double click for expanding folders.